# It works in all Browers but not in CHROME when it Live - please advice?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Here is the css code now - its simple navigation that work in all browser but not in chrome when line-  any advice ?

html

```
<div id="header">Test</div>
<nav>
<ul>

<li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>

<li><a href="#">HOME1</a></li>

<li><a href="#">HOME2</a></li>

<li><a href="#">HOME3</a></li>

<li><a href="#">HOME4</a></li>

<li><a href="#">HOME5</a></li>

</ul>
```

css

```
nav
{
    width:100%;  
    text-align:center;
}

nav ul
       {
    float:right; 
    line-height:50px;
}

nav li
{
    display:inline;
    list-type:none;
}

nav a
{
    font-family: Verdana;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #666;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color:#F7F9F8;
    padding: 40px 0 10px 0;
    text-shadow: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    color:#800040; 
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

nav a:hover
{
    transition: all .3s ease;
    padding-top: 35px;
        border-top: 5px solid #9d426b;
        background: #9d426b;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Here is the css code now - its simple navigation that work in all browser but not in chrome when line-  any advice ?

Comment: Where is code or link ?

Comment: It doesn't let me add the code, every time it keep saying add some more details ?

Comment: nav{
 width:100%;  
 text-align:center;}
 
nav ul{
 float:right; 
 line-height:50px;}

nav li{
 display:inline;
 list-type:none;}

nav a{
 font-family: Verdana;
 display:inline-block;
 
 
 text-align: center;
 color: #666;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color:#F7F9F8;
 padding: 40px 0 10px 0;
 text-shadow: none;
 font-size: 13px;
 color:#800040; 
 font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;}

nav a:hover{
 transition: all .3s ease;
 padding-top: 35px;
    border-top: 5px solid #9d426b;
    background: #9d426b;
 color:#FFFFFF;}

Comment: Post that in the question using the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29868802/edit) link.

Comment: I am trying to post the code but it saying that "Your post contain code that is not properly formatted - Indent all code by Spaces and press CTRL + K  " I did every thing but it not posting my code ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the "target" attribute to the anchor tag. Check out my example below:

http://jsfiddle.net/mLkqd5w3/

```
<li><a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">HOME</a></li>

<li><a href="http://codingclown.com" target="_blank">HOME1</a></li>
```